# FSI keeping exclusive lock on assemblies

Tags: f#

I have the statements like following in my FSI scripts

```
#I @"C:\path\to\bin\Debug\myassembly.dll"
```

When I try to build the referenced dll again I get a

```
 Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\myassembly.dll" to "bin\Debug\myassembly.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\myassembly.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have tried closing FSI window, still no help. Any idea ?

Comment: See http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/53.  This should be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: @kvb Do you know if it was fixed? I seem to still experience the issue.

Comment: @Monsignor - I believe so - there's now a `shadowcopyreferences` option you can pass to fsi.exe; in Visual Studio this can be set in the options for the F# Interactive window (and defaults to True).

Comment: @kvb Thanks, adding `"FSharp.fsiExtraParameters": ["--shadowcopyreferences+"]` to VS Code's settings solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of closing the FSI window which preserves the state. I should have run `#quit;;` command.